# HttpClient close connection

Tags: java, java-11, java-http-client

I would like to ask if this code after execution is auto-closing the connection.
Also if it fail and crash, is it still going to close connection?

```java
HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(
    HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .uri(URI.create("url_website"))
        .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
        .GET()
        .build(),
    HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
.body()
```

Comment: You can take a tcpdump and find out. It’ll also depend on the protocol version, and presence of `Connection` header.

Comment: Probably not, the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html) doesn't say it's [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html).

Answer (score 2):

The `HttpClient` uses a connection pool (one for HTTP/1.1, one for HTTP/2) so connections will be pooled - and therefore not closed immediately unless requested by the server (HTTP/1.1: `connection: close`).